# How to shutdown Broadway during runtime in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, broadway

I am using [Broadway](https://hexdocs.pm/broadway/Broadway.html) with [BroadwayKafka](https://hexdocs.pm/broadway_kafka/BroadwayKafka.Producer.html) as producer and given my use-case, I have to start and stop Broadway during runtime.

Starting Broadway during runtime already works without a problem. However, I struggle to find a way to gracefully shutdown the Broadway process. The Broadway module itself does not offer a function to stop the process (to the best of my knowledge), therefore, I currently kill the process manually via `Process.exit(broadway_pid, :kill)`. This of course works but is probably not the intended way to shutdown Broadway.

What would be the cleanest way to shutdown Broadway, without brutally killing the Broadway process?

Comment: Update - Sept 2020 `Broadway.Server` has been renamed to [`Broadway.Topology`](https://github.com/dashbitco/broadway/blob/master/lib/broadway/topology.ex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Broadway` [delegates to](https://github.com/dashbitco/broadway/blob/master/lib/broadway.ex#L928)  [`Broadway.Topology`](https://github.com/dashbitco/broadway/blob/master/lib/broadway/topology.ex) which is apparently an old good `GenServer`, so you might [`GenServer.stop/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html?#stop/3) it as

```rb
GenServer.stop(Broadway.Topology, :normal)
```

This would go through all the OTP normal shutdown procedure (callbacks etc.)

Comment: You are totally right, thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Comment: Just to be super clear, the 1st arg to `GenServer.stop/2` should be whatever you specified as your process name, e.g. if you did `Broadway.start_link(__MODULE__, name: :foo, ...` in your pipeline's `start_link`, then you would do `GenServer.stop(:foo, :normal)`